# pytorch lightning epoch_end/validation_epoch_end

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Could anybody breakdown the code and explain it to me? The part that needs help is indicated with the "#This part". I would greatly appreciate any help thanks

```
def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    batch_losses = [x["val_loss"]for x in outputs] #This part
    epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean() 
    batch_accs =  [x["val_acc"]for x in outputs]   #This part
    epoch_acc = torch.stack(batch_accs).mean()   
    return {'val_loss': epoch_loss.item(), 'val_acc': epoch_acc.item()}

def epoch_end(self, epoch, result):
    print("Epoch [{}], val_loss: {:.4f}, val_acc: {:.4f}".format( epoch,result['val_loss'], result['val_acc'])) #This part
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your provided snippet, `outputs` is a *list* containing *dict*s elements which seem to contain at least keys `"val_loss"`, and `"val_acc"`. It would be fair to assume they correspond to the validation loss and validation accuracy respectively.

Those two lines (annotated with the `# This path` comment) correspond to list comprehensions going over the elements inside the `outputs` list. The first one gathers the values of the key `"val_loss"` for each element in outputs. The second one does the same this time gathering the values of the `"val_acc"` key.

A minimal example would be:

```
## before
outputs = [{'val_loss': tensor(a), # element 0
            'val_acc': tensor(b)},

           {'val_loss': tensor(c), # element 1
            'val_acc': tensor(d)}]

## after
batch_losses = [tensor(a), tensor(c)]
batch_acc = [tensor(b), tensor(d)]
```

Answer (score 6):

In Pytorch 2.01 `validation_epoch_end` has been replaced by `on_validation_epoch_end`. Here it is the merged commentary on GitHub ([link](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/pull/16520)).

To check all the model hooks available in Pytorch Lightning you can visit this [documentation](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/_modules/lightning/pytorch/core/hooks.html#ModelHooks.on_validation_epoch_end).

Here you can see that `on_validation_epoch_end` now does not receive any `outputs` argument. Thus, in order to compute the validation loss or any metric after each epoch you should (1) create a list at the constructor of the class, (2) save the outputs in the model hook `validation_step` and (3) clean memory of the outputs after each epoch in `on_validation_epoch_end`.

Here it is a minimal working exmaple where I am measuring the F1-macro score and Cross Entropy loss in a 3 multi-class problem with a MLP model with flexible configuration of hidden layers and number of neurons:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
# from lightning.pytorch.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint ## IMPORTANT - Do not import both, just lightning.pytorch or pytorch_lightning (recommended)
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from lightning.pytorch.loggers import CSVLogger

# DATA LOADER
class DataFrameDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, labels):
        self.data = torch.tensor(dataframe.values, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.labels = torch.tensor(labels.values, dtype=torch.long)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx], self.labels[idx]


# MODEL AND MODEL HOOKS
class MLP(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_layers, output_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList()
        in_dim = input_dim

        # --> HERE STEP 1 <--
        # ATTRIBUTES TO SAVE BATCH OUTPUTS
        self.training_step_outputs = []   # save outputs in each batch to compute metric overall epoch
        self.training_step_targets = []   # save targets in each batch to compute metric overall epoch
        self.val_step_outputs = []        # save outputs in each batch to compute metric overall epoch
        self.val_step_targets = []        # save targets in each batch to compute metric overall epoch

        for hidden_dim in hidden_layers:
            self.layers.append(nn.Linear(in_dim, hidden_dim))
            in_dim = hidden_dim

        self.layers.append(nn.Linear(in_dim, output_dim))

    def forward(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers[:-1]:
            x = nn.functional.relu(layer(x))
        x = self.layers[-1](x)
        return x

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        # Train loss
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        train_loss = criterion(y_hat, y)

        # Train loss per batch in epoch
        self.log('train_loss', train_loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True )

        
        # GET AND SAVE OUTPUTS AND TARGETS PER BATCH
        y_pred = y_hat.argmax(dim=1).cpu().numpy()
        y_true = y.cpu().numpy()
        
        # --> HERE STEP 2 <--
        self.training_step_outputs.extend(y_pred)
        self.training_step_targets.extend(y_true)

        return train_loss

    def on_train_epoch_end(self):
        ## F1 Macro all epoch saving outputs and target per batch
        train_all_outputs = self.training_step_outputs
        train_all_targets = self.training_step_targets
        f1_macro_epoch = f1_score(train_all_outputs, train_all_targets, average='macro')
        self.log("training_f1_epoch", f1_macro_epoch, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)

        # free up the memory
        # --> HERE STEP 3 <--
        self.training_step_outputs.clear()
        self.training_step_targets.clear()


    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        # Val loss
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        val_loss = criterion(y_hat, y)

        # Train loss per batch in epoch
        self.log('val_loss', val_loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True )

        # GET AND SAVE OUTPUTS AND TARGETS PER BATCH
        y_pred = y_hat.argmax(dim=1).cpu().numpy()
        y_true = y.cpu().numpy()
        
        # --> HERE STEP 2 <--
        self.val_step_outputs.extend(y_pred)
        self.val_step_targets.extend(y_true)

        return val_loss

    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
        ## F1 Macro all epoch saving outputs and target per batch
        val_all_outputs = self.val_step_outputs
        val_all_targets = self.val_step_targets
        val_f1_macro_epoch = f1_score(val_all_outputs, val_all_targets, average='macro')
        self.log("val_f1_epoch", val_f1_macro_epoch, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)


        # free up the memory
        # --> HERE STEP 3 <--
        self.val_step_outputs.clear()
        self.val_step_targets.clear()

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.001, betas=(0.9, 0.999))
        return optimizer
```

Now you can create and train a model (e.g two hidden layers of 100 and 50 neurons size):

```py
# MODEL CREATION
# Assuming df is your dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("insert_path")

# Split your data into features and labels
features = df.drop(columns=['LABEL'])
labels = df['LABEL']


# Split your data into training and validation sets
features_train, features_val, labels_train, labels_val = train_test_split(features , labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# Create your custom datasets
train_dataset = DataFrameDataset(features_train, labels_train)
val_dataset = DataFrameDataset(features_val, labels_val)

# Create your Data Loaders
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=200, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=200, shuffle=False)


# Define the model (Flexible configuration)
model_MLP = MLP(input_dim=features_train.shape[1], hidden_layers=[100, 50], output_dim=3)

# TRAIN
# Define the Lightning trainer with logger callback
logger = CSVLogger(
                   save_dir = "outputs/",
                   name="my_exp_name", 
                   flush_logs_every_n_steps=500, 
                   )


checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    mode="min",
    filename="MLP-{epoch:02d}",
    dirpath="outputs/", 
    save_top_k=1, monitor="val_loss"
    
    )


# Criterion
class_weights = torch.Tensor([0.35, 0.35, 0.3])
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights, reduction='mean')



epochs = 20
device = "gpu" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"


trainer = pl.Trainer(logger=logger,
                     max_epochs=epochs, 
                     callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
                     accelerator = device
                     )

# Train the model
trainer.fit(model_MLP , train_loader, val_loader)
```

Comment: Can you explain what `step` is used for logging in `validation_step` and `training_step`? Global step, the step of the dataloader? I haven't seen it anywhere documented in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the structure, I assume you are using `pytorch_lightning`.

`validation_epoch_end()` will collect outputs from `validation_step()`, so it's a `list` of `dict` with the length of number of batch in your validation dataloader. Thus, the first two `#This part` is just unwrapping the result from your validation set.

`epoch_end()` catch the result `{'val_loss': epoch_loss.item(), 'val_acc': epoch_acc.item()}` from `validation_epoch_end()`.